# How to fix 0x800A03EC error when exporting a Datatable to Excel

Tags: asp.net, excel, vb.net, export-to-excel, excel-interop

I am trying to export a datatable to Excel and am getting the following Exception when running wb.SaveAs(path):

`Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC`

Initially I was getting this error when setting the worksheet range. I fixed this by making it non-zero indexed. However, the datatable array is still zero indexed.

Unfortunately, no additional details for the error are given.

**Code:**

```
        Dim app As New Excel.Application
        Dim wb As Excel.Workbook = app.Workbooks.Add()
        Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
        Dim strFN As String = "MyFileName.xlsx"   
        Dim dt As New DataTable

        Using da As New DataAdapter(dif)
            da.SetSelectCommand(SQL)
            da.Fill(dt)
        End Using

        ws = wb.Sheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
        DataTableToExcel(dt, ws, "TableName")

        wb.SaveAs(path)
        wb.Close()

Private Sub DataTableToExcel(dt As DataTable, ws As Excel.Worksheet, TabName As String)
    Dim arr(dt.Rows.Count, dt.Columns.Count) As Object
    Dim r As Int32, c As Int32

    For r = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
        For c = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
            arr(r, c) = dt.Rows(r).Item(c)
        Next
    Next

    ws.Name = TabName   
    c = 0

    For Each column As DataColumn In dt.Columns
        If column.ColumnName.Length > 4 Then
            If column.ColumnName.Substring(column.ColumnName.Length - 4, 4) = "_ID" Then
                ws.Cells(1, c + 1) = column.ColumnName.Replace("_", " ").Substring(0, column.ColumnName.Length - 4)
            Else
                ws.Cells(1, c + 1) = column.ColumnName.Replace("_", " ")
            End If
        Else
            ws.Cells(1, c + 1) = column.ColumnName.Replace("_", " ")
        End If

        c += 1
    Next

    ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 1), ws.Cells(dt.Rows.Count, dt.Columns.Count))(1).Value = arr
End Sub
```

**UPDATE:**

I've managed to stop the error from occuring by changing SaveAs() to SaveCopyAs().

The file now exports but when I open it, all there is are column names and only the first value of the first column/row.

Comment: Please use `try/catch` and capture the full exception. Also, try export less data with this code; probably there's a error with the content of the datatable...can you share the datatable's structure and some sample data?

Comment: Is you web site running as x32, or x64 bits? That error message looks like a miss-match bit size. If your web site and project is running as x64 bits, then you have to install the x64 bit version of Excel for this to work. you might be able for testing to set your project to x86 and try that. But this can crop up as an issue down the road, since most web servers are now running as x64 bits. But, try setting your project from "any cpu" to a project running as x86. Or you can/could try and install a x64 bit version of Excel

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes, the function is already in a try/catch, that is the full error message. I cannot share the data unfortunately as it is data I am not at liberty to share. I have tried exporting multiple different tables, sometimes filtered down to only one or two records. I get the same error every time.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal, the website is running as x64 and the excel version is also x64. I've tried running the website as x86 and get the same error.

Comment: Instead of using Excel and interop you could use one of the many libraries that generate real Excel files without using Excel, like Epplus, NPOI or ClosedXML. With, eg , Epplus you can write `ws.Cells.LoadFromDataTable(table)` or `LoadFromCollection(someList)`, `LoadFromDataReader()` to fill a sheet from a DataTable, `IEnumerable<T>` or `IDbDataReader`

Comment: If you have a web site you **can't** use Excel interop anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Launching Excel just to export data to an Excel file is overkill. For web sites it's completely impractical for several reasons:

- You need a license for *every* user of the *site*. That's a lot of money.
- It's way too easy to leave Excel open, slowly eating up the server's RAM and CPU.
- It's just too slow

`xlsx` is a ZIP package containing well-defined XML files, so one can create them directly, use the Open XML SDK or one of the many open source libraries that make this a lot easier, like Epplus, NPOI or ClosedXML.

For example, Epplus allows filling an Excel sheet from a DataTable, IEnumerable or IDbDataReader with a single call:

```
Dim dt As DataTable = ...

Dim fi New FileInfo(SomePath)
Using p As New ExcelPackage(fi)
    Dim ws = p.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(sheetName)
    ws.Cells("A1").LoadFromDataTable(dt, PrintHeaders:=True)
    p.Save()
End Using
```

You can also use [LoadFromDataReader](https://www.epplussoftware.com/docs/5.6/api/OfficeOpenXml.ExcelRangeBase.html#OfficeOpenXml_ExcelRangeBase_LoadFromDataReader_System_Data_IDataReader_System_Boolean_) and avoid loading all the data into memory:

```
Using cmd As New SqlCommand(sql,connection)
    connection.Open()
    Using reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        Dim fi New FileInfo(SomePath)
        Using p As New ExcelPackage(fi)
            Dim ws = p.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(sheetName)
            ws.Cells("A1").LoadFromDataReader(reader, PrintHeaders:=True)
            p.Save()
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
```